# C++11 enum class namespace block

Tags: c++, c++11, namespaces, enum-class

I have an `enum class` in C++11:

```
enum class eDays{ SUNDAY, MONDAY, /*...*/ };
```

The `enum class` sets the namespace for the values so it has to be used like:

```
eDays::SUNDAY
```

I want to set an namespace block so I won't need to specify the namespace each time something like:

```
namespace eDays {
    vector<eDays> vec = { MONDAY, SUNDAY, /*...*/ };
}
```

Instead of:

```
vector<eDays> vec = { eDays::MONDAY, eDays::SUNDAY, /*...*/ };
```

What am I missing?

Comment: Why don't you just use an enum instead of an enum class? An enum class works like a class so `eDays` is not a namespace but a class name, and you just can't not mention the class name to use its static members.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

With enum classes, you cannot.

As Benjamin Barrois put it, "An enum class works like a class so `eDays` is not a namespace but a class name"; [using directives](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/keyword/using) may not apply.

If you want to be able to write the following, there are other solutions.

```
std::vector<eDays> vec = { Monday, Tuesday, /*...*/  };
```

---

#### Actual namespace + `enum`

```
namespace eDays
{
    enum t { Monday, Tuesday, /*...*/ };
}
```

#### Actual namespace + (static) constants

```
namespace eDays
{
    static const int Monday  = 0;
    static const int Tuesday = 1;
    // ...
}
```

---

Both will let you write:

```
{
    using namespace eDays;
    std::vector<int> vec = { Monday, Tuesday, /*...*/  }; // or <t>
}
```